# Access 2010 Database - Count number of instances

Tags: database, recordset, countif

I'm a complete Access noob and I'm creating a database to keep track of orders shipped for work.  I've got two tables in the database, one keeping track of the units shipped and the other keeping track of each purchase order and how many more items until that order can be closed.  What I want to do is, basically, like a COUNTIF function from Excel on the entries from Table A and transfer to Table B.  An example:

Table A has:

PO123

PO123

PO234

PO123

What I want Table 2 to do is count the number of instances of each PO and display the count in a field, like so:

Table B:

Row 1 Field 1: PO123

Row 1 Field 2: 3

Row 2 Field 1: PO234

Row 2 Field 2: 1

Anyone have any ideas?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what the name of the field was, so I'm going to assume it's POTYPE. You need to create a query in Access, and go to the SQL view. Then you can do a query like

```
Select POTYPE, Count(POTYPE) From TableA Group By POTYPE
```

Comment: Thanks Erik!  That helped get me started.  The query works and opens in a new tab.  Now I have two fields: Purchase Order # and CountOfPurchase Order #.  What I would like to do it have the value of CountOfPurchase Order# move to TableB, is there a way to transfer the data automatically when I refresh the query?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a work around.  In addition to my table of orders, I created a separate table called "Known POs," which I have to manually update for now with the PO number and the total due. Using the query you helped me create, I was able to count the POs used and check it against the total due through the new table I created.  Thanks again for your help!